# Is “what color is she” colloquial?

Tags: spoken-english

I have a pony.
**What color is she?**
That’s sounds always wrong for me. Is it colloquial?

I would always say:
**What color does she have?**

What is more common?

Comment: While both are grammatically correct, be aware of the context.  If "she" is a person and you are asking about the colour of her skin, (1) You probably don't need to ask and (2) if you do, then there are more tactful ways of doing so.  If you are not asking about a the colour of a person's skin, you could edit to make that context clear.

Comment: Think about how you would say it as a statement.  "She is gray", not "She has gray."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*What colour is she?*" is correct in English. We speak about things *being* a colour rather than *having* a colour. The other option you propose would be incorrect in English for most contexts. This is in contrast to some other languages where colours may be applied to objects in the way you suggest.

Although the names of colours can be nouns when they are used for the colour they represent, as a property of an object they are nearly always adjectives.